# Why was the Balrog beneath Moria

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring, balrogs

From Lord of the Rings:

> Saruman: Moria... You fear to go into those mines. The dwarves delved too greedily and too deep. You know what they awoke in the darkness of Khazad-dum... shadow and flame.

So, the dwarves awoke the Balrog beneath Moria. But why was the Balrog there in the first place?

Comment: Basement living is very trendy nowadays.

Comment: You said so yourself: it was awoken. Where else would you try and sleep for milllennia as a balrog? I know where I wouldn't sleep: In some random forest or field in Middle Earth.

Comment: Could be Balrogs everywhere if you dig deep enough. Fourth Age oil companies, beware!

Comment: No book handy for a supported answer, but the idea is that the Balrog had fled the overthrow of Angband at the end of the First Age and was hiding. There's no particular reason *why* it was under Moria, other than a really unfortunate coincidence for the Dwarves of Khazad-Dûm.

Comment: It probably fled there after the fall of thangorodrim but I expect someone with better knowledge and quotes will be able to clarify in answer-worthy form.

Comment: Just a note that the line quoted is from Jackson's FotR film and not present in the books. The question itself is still valid though.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe The Balrog was in there *before* the dwarfs, and quite possibly before the mountains existed over the top.

Comment: OK people, that's a whole lot of funny comments. We don't really hate fun, but if *everyone* leaves their wit here, it's going to be a very full comment section. I've [moved the comments to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119347/discussion-on-question-by-shade-why-was-the-balrog-beneath-moria); feel free to continue sharing as much wit as you like there.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Silmarillion, Chapter XXIV Of the Voyage of Eärendil and the War of Wrath:

> The Balrogs were destroyed, save some few that fled
> and hid themselves in caverns inaccessible at the roots of the earth

Comment: Balrog: I'm safe, this cavern is inaccessible. - Dwarves: Hold my beer.

Comment: Well, it *was* inaccessible until the dwarves came along.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri More like: “Hold my axe.”

Comment: @DavidFoerster although beer is relevant too for dwarves.

Comment: I love all these comments , mods plz dont delete them !

Comment: @DavidFoerster hold my beer while I grab this pick-axe.

Comment: "Hold my _ale_".

Comment: @EmanueleCiriachi They live in caves. They clearly drink lager.